# JavaFX - How to have user draw boundary on screen overlay

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, overlay, draw

I am making an application that uses pixel recognition. One integral part of the application is it needs to have a general idea of where a item of interest will appear during the video game. I want to make a tool so the user can manually draw a box, my method can read the size of the box he drew, then can save that data as two `Point` variables.

Extremely oversimplified example below:

[image: Test Video Game]

Let's say my program needs to now know the rough estimation of where the `Princess` is. The user presses the `Calbirate` button and then clicks and drags on the game and a red square such as below appears:

[image: Calibration example]

As soon as the user lets go over the mouse button, the program saves the coordinates (400, 15) and (480, 190) which is the start and end points of the box. My program then knows from what `Point` ranges the object we are looking for is in.

How can this be done? Note that this functionality is extremely common in many famous Screenshot programs such as `ShareX` or `Greenshot`.

Comment: Just do it - there's not really enough information in your question to answer, but basically just register mouse listeners with whatever Node is rendering the image and add and modify a rectangle to the appropriate container. Post a [MCVE] showing what you've tried if you get stuck.

Comment: I guess if you need an example, I do something along these lines in my [Mandelbrot example](https://github.com/james-d/ZoomingMandelbrot) (see the code in MandelbrotExplorerController.java).